# How to display specific category on single post page?

Tags: page-specific-settings

How can I display only the specific category when accessing the posts related to that category? For example, I want to show only CSR Events under Categories When accessing posts related to CSR events. Here's the link to CSR post https://www.mi-eq.com/blood-donation-compaign/

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoTfk.jpg

Similarly, when visiting posts related to other categories, only the specific category will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will modify the arguments for the WP Categories widget so that the only category displayed will be the current category. Add this to your theme's/child theme's `functions.php` or create a plugin for this code:

```
/**
 * Modify the arguments for the Categories widget on single templates so that
 * only the current category is returned.
 *
 * @param array $cat_args Arguments passed to wp_list_categories(),
 * @param array $instance Category widget instamce.
 *
 * @return array wp_list_categories() arguments.
 */
function wpse_widget_categories_args( $cat_args, $instance ) {
    // Bail if this isn't the single template.
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return $cat_args;
    }

    global $wp_query;

    // Get term id for current category.
    $current_term = get_term_by(
        'slug',
        $wp_query->query['category_name'],
        'category'
    );

    // Get term objects for all terms except the current term.
    $exclude_categories = get_categories(
        [
            'exclude' => [ $current_term->term_id ],
        ]
    );

    // Use our list of excluded terms to ensure results are only returned for the current term.
    $cat_args['exclude'] = wp_list_pluck( $exclude_categories, 'term_id' );

    return $cat_args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_categories_args', 'wpse_widget_categories_args', 10, 2 );
```

Example with this code enabled:
[image]

Example without code enabled (cropped because there are lots of categories):
[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, I have copied and pasted your code to function.php but it turned out to be no categories shown. Please see screenshot here - https://ibb.co/gZt2zQF . Anything wrong with the code? Can anyone else help?

Comment: Sorry that didn't work for you @DavidLee. I did double check it and the code works for me.I added a screenshot of what I'm seeing -- When I'm on a single post, the WP Categories widget will just show the main category of the current post.

Comment: Could it be there are no categories to display, so get_categories() will return an empty array? I have tested with following code and categories name can be returned. Is there any other changes need to make other than functions.php?

Comment: These two are my categories:
https://www.mi-eq.com/?cat=73
https://www.mi-eq.com/?cat=74 

which respectively redirected to 
https://www.mi-eq.com/category/main-events/
https://www.mi-eq.com/category/corporate-social-responsibilies/

Answer (score 0):

I have copied and pasted your code to function.php but it turned out to be no categories shown. Please see screenshot here - https://ibb.co/gZt2zQF . Anything wrong with the code? Can anyone else help?